# Auto generated IDs causing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined, i want plugin to map DB generated IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, treeview

i am using **Bootstrap-TreeView** Plugin and i am getting following error, what i have done is that i have already rendered the tree view, now i wanna have something similar to `"selected=selected"' for all the nodes that i wanna show as checked.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

Following is my code where i am trying to set the nodes by id

```
 var catgories_for_edit = {!! json_encode($product->categories) !!};

     $.each(catgories_for_edit,function(index,categoryObject){

            $categTreeView.treeview('checkNode', [categoryObject.id, { silent: true } ]);

        });
```

Json data:

```
// var catgories_for_edit returns following data   
 [{"id":21,"parent_id":null,"lft":17,"rgt":24,"depth":2,"name":"admin","created_at":"2016-12-29 21:42:25","updated_at":"2017-01-02 08:30:23"}]
```

referring to following plugin 
https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview

Comment: I am also facing same issue, Could you please share how did you resolve it?